# How to parse jSON file with double quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, json

I have a CSV file full of array values and want to read it in PHP. So I used [Mr Data Converter](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) (as suggested on StackOverflow) to convert my CSV file into a jSON file, which I can then easily parse & decode in PHP. Unfortunately, the jSON file I got is filled with **"" (double quotes) and \n (new lines)** all over the place and PHP can't seem to decode it. I've tried other online conversion tools, but they all seem to have the same problem. Here is an example of the jSON string:

```
[{"text":"This is some example "text"","name":"Thomas Cohen"},{"text":"This is "another" example text","name":"Steve Mambo"}]
```

If I remove the double quotes, PHP can parse it without problems. But I can't do that for the entire file as it's way too large.

How can PHP parse this jSON?

Comment: It is not _valid_ JSON so it can't be parsed without modification.  Decode functions of any kind require a valid encoding.

Comment: just parse the csv file directly, php has functions for that

Answer (score 1):

That JSON is invalid. The `"` characters inside strings must be escaped:

```
"This is some example \"text\""
```

Any JSON generator should escape them correctly though.

Possibly you are copy/pasting the JSON into your PHP source and failing to properly escape characters when you manually turn it into a string literal. Make sure you escape any character with special meaning in a PHP string (such as `\` and `"`.

Comment: this jSON generator I used (Mr Data Converter) happens not to escape quotes inside strings. do you know of any other one that does?